# how close google sign-in window after signing in - android app

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I have added google sign-in to my android app. google sign-in window opens in the web browser and it works. But there is no way to go back to the app after signing in. **window.close();** is not working on the android. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into invoking Google Sign In via a Chrome Custom Tab window rather than the system. browser. This will give you a more integrated UX:.

```kotlin
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, signInUrl)
```

You can run my [Android Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android) to evalute this type of UX.